# Todayview openurl - calls didFinishLaunchingWithOptions multiple times

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

i am currently playing arround with an ios8 todayview extension.
i call `[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:nil];` to open the app containing the extension.

in some cases: about 1 out of 10 launches (app closed)  - the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` gets called more than once.

i tried working arround with a bool value `BOOL appStarted` setting it to `YES` at the end of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.
and added an alertview at the beginning of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` - but it seems that the function is called more than once and the bool is always NO

any idea?

regards

Comment: if i run my custom uri via safari the problem never happens only with the `extensionContext`

Comment: ok seems to be one of my closed-source 3rd party libraries wich is  modifing the nsrunloop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually used a 3rd party source closed library wich seems to mangle the NSRunloop - moved the initialization code out of "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" fixed the problem